# Upgrading Ubuntu from 16.04. to 18.04

Tags: 16.04, boot, 18.04, upgrade

I have tried to update ubuntu machine from 16.0.4.5 to 18.0.4 (by following the standard procedure to run do-release-upgrade). Despite several attempts post upgrade machine does not boot up. A black screen keeps blinking after UTMP service started.

[image: black screen]
<sup>**Ubuntu 18.04 black screen in VMware**</sup>

Here is what I have tried:

1. Updated the owner of .Xuathority and .ICEAuthority.
2. Verified that tmp has enough permissions.
3. Uncomment WayLand in custom.conf under /etc/gdm3/ so that Xorg is used instead of wayland
4. Switched from gdm3 to lightdm.
   I noticed a different issue - Ubuntu boots till login. Post entering 
   the credentials system comes back to login window. I tried couple of 
   suggestions online to fix this, but none of the solutions solved
   problem.

I tried to install Ubuntu with the following virtual machine applications:

1. VMware Fusion for Mac - 11.0.2
2. VMware ESXi - 6.5

Ensured that the computer has the minimum configuration suggested for Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Did you try booting to runlevel 3 (i.e. without graphics)?

Comment: Yeah, booting into run level 3 works perfectly fine.

Comment: Might be worth checking if this helps: https://askubuntu.com/a/1131525/874649  (installing nvidia-driver-390)

Comment: I run my ubunutu on virtual machine(VMWare Fusion). Does this installation still need nvidia graphics driver? Anyways I tried to install nvidia; that does not solve my issue eitherr :(