# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes suddenly and give no logs

Tags: gnome, interface

I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed in my working computer. All of a sudden, it seems to me that when I use any interface interaction such as clicking somewhere, it freezes. I see that it keeps running my terminal commands, saving in the disk and everything. Only the interface freezes. I tried to wait some hours, but nothing happens. So I have to restart, and when I log in again, there is no logs. I happened twice to me today, one while I was writing this post, but it seems to be random to me. Sometimes it takes one week running (I don't turn off the computer) and sometimes several times in a day like today. 
The specs are: i7-4930K, 64gb of Ram, 2 x 1Tb HDs and a GeForce GT 740 as video card. 
The programs that are usually running are Chrome, terminal, gedit, matlab and a latex editor.

Please, someone can at least help me to track the problem? It is hard to work this way...

Many thanks in advance,

Cayo

Edit:
Some commands outputs:

```
$ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
ls: cannot access '/home/cayo/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': No such file or directory

$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            62G        2.2G         58G         34M        1.8G         60G
Swap:          975M          0B        975M

$ glxinfo | grep 'version'
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 418.56
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 418.56
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 418.56
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
    GL_EXT_shader_implicit_conversions, GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix,
```

Comment: When the system freeze have you tried accessing ttys?
If you can access it may be a graphic driver issue, have you tried reinstalling the Nvidia drivers?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `free -h`. What version Nvidia driver? Report back to @heynnema

Comment: Sorry for taking so long. No, I did not try to reinstall the driver because I tried before to format everything, so I did a fresh install of the latest driver from NVIDIA.

Comment: And I added what @heynnema asked...

Comment: Check if the solution here helps: https://askubuntu.com/a/1131525/874649

Comment: With not much to go on, I have to ask you to check a couple of real basic things... 1) check that your BIOS is current, and 2) although it'll take quite some time, run `memtest` from the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB GRUB menu... normally I'd ask to run 4/4 passes, but in your case, get at least 1/4.

Comment: @Elias they already have the latest Nvidia drivers installed.

Comment: Maybe this Nouveau might work in my case?
Sorry @heynnema, I don't understand what you mean by if my BIOS is current, you mean the version?

Comment: BIOS, and firmware, are the basic code that makes your machine work. To check your BIOS version, in `terminal` do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, take that output, along with your make/model of your computer, to the manufacturor's web site, go to support, and check there if there is a newer BIOS and any firmware updates available.

Comment: Yes, I did it, my motherboard is an Asus P9X79, and the latest firmware is the one I have, 4801 (that is actually a beta version)